# Context free grammars for generating mathematical expressions

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I am looking for some resources on CFGs capable of generating mathematical expressions. For example an expression like the one below

> $expression = a + 2b + 4ac$

Where a,b,c are some terminal symbols. Please note that I am not looking for a grammar that  generates the above expression, but a repository which I can browse for similar grammars. The more complex the grammars the better.

EDIT: Changed expression to TeX

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun Sorry I am not sure I understand. There is no special symbols required for this expression. I dont see how Tex would improve it. However, here it is updated

Comment: @CaptainZ Everything is better in TeX :)

Comment: What is your purpose? (write a compiler, learn about CFGs, ...) The book "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation" by Hopcroft, Motwani and Ullman is a good reference to learn more about CFGs. If you want to write a compiler, first learn a little basic facts about CFGs and use some grammars you found online.

Comment: Something as [this](http://maestros.unitec.edu/~efutch/small-c__english_version_.html) you need? This is a grammar of Small C, written in EBNF.